# Pop up a dynamic choice list when pressing a button

Tags: android, list, spinner

i have a little problem.

Let's say we have an EditText, a Button and an arraylist of string with x values.

When pressing on button, i want to pop a choice list (like a spinner) with values of arraylist. Then, get the string of choosen item and put it in the EditText.

How can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I've down voted your question. You should research before asking questions here. Try some code, then come with doubts/ errors in the code. 
This is how you get the text of the item selected-
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AutoCompleteTextView` this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_box);
    ed.getText().toString();

public void Thespinner()
{
    yourspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (this, R.array."YOUR ARRAY NAME", android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    yourspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> yourspinner, View view,int pos, long id)
{
        ed.setText(yourspinner.getSelectedItem());
}
```